# how to disable access time settings in Debian linux

Tags: linux, mount, performance, timestamps

Performance Best Practices for MongoDB implies that:

> Most file systems will maintain metadata for the last time a file was
>   accessed. While this may be useful for some applications, in a
>   database it means that the file system will issue a write every time
>   the database accesses a page, which will negatively impact the
>   performance and throughput of the system.

For mongoDB installation I need to disable access time on my Debian, how to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To disable the writing of access times, you need to mount the filesystem(s) in question with the `noatime` option.

To mount an already mounted filesystem with the `noatime` option, do the following:

```
mount /home -o remount,noatime
```

To make the change permanent, update your `/etc/fstab` and add `noatime` to the `options` field.

For example.

Before:

```
/dev/mapper/sys-home  /home  xfs  nodev,nosuid         0       2
```

After:

```
/dev/mapper/sys-home  /home  xfs  nodev,nosuid,noatime  0       2
```

Comment: I have a line like this: `/dev/mapper/localhost-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1`.

in your case you dont have errors. Should I add `noatime` in `errors`?

Comment: You add the `noatime` option, like this: `/dev/mapper/localhost-root / ext4 noatime,errors=remount-ro 0 1`

Comment: we have another option called: `nodiratime`, should I use that too?

Comment: `nodiratime`is to  not update directory inode access times on that filesystem.

Comment: ... and just to be clear - `noatime` is a superset of `nodiratime` (ie if you specify `noatime` you don't need to specify `nodiratime` as well) - see kernel developer Andrew Morton's [comment](http://lwn.net/Articles/245002/).

Comment: @mjturner great answer +1. Thank you so much.

Comment: @phpgeek Debian systems tend to use `relatime` which is an efficient halfway house between `noatime` and `atime`.